# Linq to SQL not showing up even after installing module via tools and features

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Tried to use LinqToSQL and didn't see it when selecting a new item so I installed the module via tools and features and hit modify to install , then rebooted! Going back into tools and features the Linq to SQL tools is now checked , but I still can't use it as there is no selection in add item search for LINQ! 
This with visual studio 2019 with all updates loaded! I don`t have a code sample because I can't load the LinqToSQL item yet!

Thanks

Pete

[image: linq feature page]

Comment: I was trying to use LinqtoSQL under a .net CORE WPF , but If I load up a windows forms application framework application , then I can add a LinqtoSQL item! I was under the impression core WPF would use t5he LINQtoSQL method!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer , I was under the impression Linq to SQL was the new way to access data and Entity Framework was the old way , but its the other way around! Linq to SQL is no longer supported!  I`ll leave this here in case some other nubie makes the same mistake!

Pete